# WinAPI equivalent of Win32_ComputerSystem.PCSystemType

Tags: c++, winapi

My app needs to check if the computer is a laptop, i find accessing this property through WMI to be hard and slow, is there a win32 equivalent? I've searched on `GetSystemPowerStatus` but this isn't 'foolproof' as a workstation may have a battery, accessing WMI always worked for me but i'm porting an app from c# and c++ isn't that friendly with WMI.

Is there a win32 API i can use? Or does this property takes a guess as well with the battery API's?

Comment: Using [_bstr_t](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zthfhkd6.aspx), [_variant_t](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x295h94e.aspx), and [_com_ptr_t](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/417w8b3b.aspx) makes WMI accessible from C++ as easily as you are used to with C#. Throwing in the (undocumented) `_com_util::CheckError` helper (include *comdef.h*), makes the resulting code near identical to .NET code.